# DbContext scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
Scaffold-DbContext  'Data Source=""; Database=""; User Id="";Password="";TrustServerCertificate=Yes' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

while running this command i get the following error:

```
ClientConnectionId:f433cc07-6534-4bb4-ad0e-eab15d75ed67
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
Invalid column name 'has_filter'.
Invalid column name 'filter_definition'.
```

Comment: Include your `dbContext` class and `Database Table design`  after executing the migration command for better clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core does not support SQL Server 2005, or database with a compatibility level under 110. Upgrade to a supported version or alter the compatibility level:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

Comment: I have sql server 2016

Comment: And the compatibility of the database is 100 or more?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '110'.

Completion time: 2022-07-25T19:31:49.7541152+05:30

Comment: Invalid column name 'has_filter'. Invalid column name 'filter_definition'. why this error i dont have any columns named this

Comment: It is system colums!

Comment: Please run: 
SELECT @@VERSION 
and
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;